# How can I higlight PHP code in the Drupal 6 editor?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, tinymce, syntax-highlighting, wysiwyg

I have been looking for a good editor with syntax highlighting for php code to be used in the drupal 6 node body.

I would like to clear one thing first, **I DO NOT need a syntax highligter for a code "posted" or "displayed" in the node.** But I need to write php codes for some pages and writing them like a text without any highlighting, is pretty annoying.

As you can see below, I would like the php syntax `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` to be highlighted.

[image]

I tried many combinations and not found anything that I really desire.
below are some things that I tried...

> I tried TinyMCE with codemagic, codemirror, editarea. But nothing
>   really works as they should.
>   adding to the above, trying to write and preserve code in any wysiwyg editor is a real pain in the a**.
>
> Then I tried [colorer](http://drupal.org/project/colorer) module but am facing many problems and not
>   even a single bug report and issue of this module is fixed.

So isn't there a way to write php code as code and not as text inside the drupal nodes..?? 
Or is it that nobody bothered about it because anyone hardly writes php code inside nodes..?
I hope am not the only one and some solution to it does exist.

Comment: Writing PHP in nodes is one of those things that doesn't fall into the "Drupal Best Practices", so that could be a possibility.

Comment: It could be..! but anyway, my site is still on localhost and in developing stage. So I upgraded to Drupal 7 yesterday. Now I can use that ACE editor...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ACE editor](http://drupal.org/project/ace_editor) works really well as a code editor for `<textarea>`s, and it has a Drupal module. ACE is well maintained, so I'd check them out as an alternative to colorer, TinyMCE, et al.

*Edit:* However, it's only for Drupal 7, which won't help...

Comment: So you are saying that there is nothing that can help me in this problem...??!!

Comment: Other than the apparently abandoned colorer, I don't think so. However, ACE appears to be relatively easy to use—GitHub and a ton of other places use it. It's probably relatively trivial to backport the Drupal 7 module to work with 6.

Comment: Also, instead of doing the full-on ACE module, some people have made it work as a Wysiwyg plugin/editor. The Wysiwyg module works fine on Drupal 6, and it would probably be even easier to modify Wysiwyg rather than backporting the full module. This person did it on D6 - http://drupal.org/node/1377948

Comment: Ace works well, made an ExtJS implementation of it for some js/css/html highlighting, Works like a charm but I would advise against diving into the source.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, it doesn't work in iOS or Android—it won't bring up the on-screen keyboard in either. Someday they'll hopefully fix that.